# How to assign variables to selected roots of a polynomial equation?

Tags: equation-solving

I have a polynomial equation like the below, and I want to assign variables to the roots that are not pure imaginary. How I can do this?

```
Root[Sqrt[c33 c44 s^4 + (c13^2 + 2 c13 c44 - c11 c33) s^2 + c11 c44]]
```

c33, c44, c13, c11, c33 are constants.

Comment: What have you tried? *Root* is for root objects (and your example is not even a correct use), are you sure it's not *Solve* you're after?

Comment: I used Solve too but its still not working!
as I've mentioned before what I want is the roots of prior equation which are not pure imaginary.

Comment: I would be thankful if you help me with any idea of how to find that and allocate a variable to that!

Comment: Sqrt[c33 c44* s^4 + (c13^2 + 2 c13 c44 - c11 c33)*s^2 + c11 c44]=0

Comment: s is the variable and all those "c" ones are some constants!

Comment: they can get assigned by any real values!

Comment: The roots of `Sqrt[c33 c44* s^4 + (c13^2 + 2 c13 c44 - c11 c33)*s^2 + c11 c44]=0` are the same as the roots of `c33 c44* s^4 + (c13^2 + 2 c13 c44 - c11 c33)*s^2 + c11 c44=0`, so the `Sqrt` part is superfluous.

Comment: Just use `Solve[c33 c44 s^4 + (c13^2 + 2 c13 c44 - c11 c33) s^2 + c11 c44 == 
  0, s, Reals]` to get the real roots (assuming the constants are real too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(* Clear stuff *)
ClearAll[c33, c44, c13, c11, s, myvars, vars]


(* Assign some values to constants *)
c33 = -7;
c44 = -1/3;
c13 = 13;
c11 = 11;

(*Solve it *)
sols = Solve[Sqrt[c33 c44*s^4 + (c13^2 + 2 c13 c44 - c11 c33)*s^2 + c11 c44] == 0, s];

(* pick out those with non-zero real component *)
sols2 = Select[s /. sols, Re[#] != 0 &];

(* make an array of variables vars[1],vars[2]... for however many needed *)
myvars = Array[vars, Length@sols2];

(* assign the solutions to generated variables *)
Evaluate@myvars = sols2;

(* how many were there? *)
Length@myvars

(*look at one of them *)
vars[1]
```

You could also just dispense with the latter parts, just reference the vector of solutions:

```
sols2[[1]]
```

All of this is covered in the documentation and tutorials. It is worth your while to read them...